# How to prove shorter nat comparisons like 10000 > 1 for sigma types in Coq?

Tags: coq

Currently I have:

```
Require Import Coq.Init.Specif.
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith. 

Definition Test(s: {x : nat | x > 1}) := True.

Lemma pTwoGt1 : 2 > 1. apply gt_Sn_n. Qed.

Eval compute in Test (exist _ 2 pTwoGt1).
```

1. How can I prove for randomly high numbers, like: 10000 > 1 ?
2. How can I simplify creation of a value for this sigma type? Currently I have to have separate few lines of code with a prove and even to have a name for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), you don't have to recurse all the way down the unary definition of 10000: you can just go two steps:

```
Lemma pLotsGt1 : 10000 > 1.
Proof.
  apply le_n_S, le_n_S, Nat.le_0_l.
Qed.
```

Unfortunately, the proof term is still rather big:

```
pLotsGt1 = 
le_n_S 1 (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (...)))))))))))))))))))))))
  (le_n_S 0 (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (...))))))))))))))))))))))
     (Nat.le_0_l (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (S (...)))))))))))))))))))))))
     : Init.Nat.of_num_uint
         (Number.UIntDecimal (Decimal.D1 (Decimal.D0 (Decimal.D0 (Decimal.D0 (Decimal.D0 Decimal.Nil)))))) >
       1
```

because `le_n_S` takes the (unary-encoded) big number as one of its arguments.

**EDIT**: Looking further, I notice that Coq actually represents big numbers like this as a list of digits. You can see it above, where we're calling `of_num_uint` on what is basically the list `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Unfolding things a bit, `of_num_uint` boils down to calls to `Init.Nat.tail_addmul`, which has a specification lemma:

```
Nat.tail_addmul_spec: forall r n m : nat, Nat.tail_addmul r n m = r + n * m
```

so you could actually handle your example with a decision procedure on the list of digits which would avoid having to construct the big unary expansion at any point.

Of course, this depends on where your "random" numbers are coming from in the first place. Presumably not from number literals in the source, so you probably are starting with the `nat` anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly Coq 8.12 do some automated optimisations and give me this message: To avoid stack overflow, large numbers in nat are
interpreted as applications of Init.Nat.of_num_uint.
[abstract-large-number,numbers]

Answer (score 1):

You could follow chapter 7 of this book https://zenodo.org/record/4457887#.Ydbktdso-cM which covers how ordinals are formalized in the Math Comp library.

The key ingredient is to use a computational definition of `>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what Enrico has in mind, but here is one possible way to proceed, using mathcomp finite types (which enable computation) instead of `nat` and ssreflect tactics language. Note that `I_n.+1` is the finite type of ordinals of size n+1, i.e., naturals from 0 to n.

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Definition Test n (s : exists x : 'I_n.+1, x > 1) := true.

Lemma exists_gt_1 n (lt1n : 1 < n) : exists x : 'I_n.+1, x > 1.
Proof. by exists ord_max. Qed.

Eval compute in @Test 2 (exists_gt_1 2 is_true_true).
Eval compute in @Test 10000 (exists_gt_1 10000 is_true_true).
```

Comment: It still looks like that Sigma types in Coq are much harder to use compared to F* refinement types, because they need explicit proofs that are separate.